# Как обнаружить переход на новую строку при чтении txt файла в java?

Tags: java

**Дано:**
Есть файл - "1.txt".
Есть также код, который читает файл по строкам, по очереди.

**Нужно:**
Допустим, я считываю файл, и мне нужно учесть на конце строки *переход на новую строку*, чтобы при разбиении:
`MyLine.split("Символ перехода на новую троку")`или проверке:
`if(MyLine.equals("Символ перехода на новую строку"))` на экране
выводилось бы:`"Символ перехода на новую строку"` ,например, так:
`System.out.println("$")`
Мне важен факт самого детектирования символа разрыва строки. Это можно было бы сделать через подсчёт итераций в цикле `i++`, но мне это не нужно. Спасибо.

**Вопрос:** Как детекировать (обнаружить) на конце строки сам символ разрыва строки(переход на новую строку).

```
package j;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class J {
public static void Cool_Read(String FileName){
    //file must be on home folder of project
    // and file name must be for e.g. 1.txt
    try {Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(FileName));
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String MyLine = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(MyLine);}}
        catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Cool_Read("1.txt");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: каждая итерация вашего цикла - новая строка. в чем проблема?

Comment: Я получаю ошибку в своей полной программе, если строка - (пустая + enter), а мне такую строку нужно прочитать как `$`, например!

Comment: приведите фрагмент файла, который читаете, где возникает такая ошибка

Comment: Ошибка была в коде, я её исправил ).
Как теперь подсчитать строки, которые пустые, в которых только символ enter(переход на новую строку)?Я просто знаю что можно сделать что-то типа `if(MyString.equals("/n"))` или как то иначе, но точного ответа я не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу понять, в чем проблема... Читаем файл, проверяем каждую строку не пустая ли она, получаем вилку для пустой и не пустой строки, дописываем нужную логику для каждого варианта:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        coolRead("1.txt");
    }

    public static void coolRead(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName), "UTF-8")){
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Empty line");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы прокатит, спасибо). Проверю-отпишусь.

Comment: Я сделал так при вилке подсчитал кол-во enter (переходов на новую строку). Код рабочий спасибо. Помогло `line.isEmpty();`